# Eclipse : Run an external software in editor view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse to edit almost any file that I code. But for some, I prefer to use gEdit (for instance CoffeeScript files).

I wondered if there was a way to somehow embed the UI of gEdit (or any other software) in the Editor view of Eclipse. I could use my favorite editor in an unified environment and this could also bring the richness of the Eclipse environment to those files (even if I'm well aware that most of it won't work).

But is it ever possible ? Better, is there already a plugin for that ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

> I wondered if there was a way to somehow embed the UI of gEdit (or any other software) in the Editor view of Eclipse.

No, there isn't.

However, you can execute an external editor from Eclipse.

From the main Eclipse menu, left click on Window -> Preferences.

On the Preferences dialog, left click General -> Editors -> File Associations.

[image: File Associations]

For any file type, you can associate one or more editors.  These editors can be external to Eclipse.

Once you've done this, you can bring up your external editor by double clicking on the module name in the Package Explorer.

After you're finished editing with an external editor, refresh the module so Eclipse knows you've made changes.

Comment: Yes, I already know (and use) that. But the idea was to have one window for all my codes... Well, thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

SWT allows to integrate apps using OLE. Unluckily this is obviously available only when running on Windows.

For more info, see [this article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseMicrosoftIntegration/article.html) by Lars Vogel.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I need !... on Linux :-P. At least, this is a place to start. Thanks.